# Mongodb query to match a value in a subdocument identified by a number

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got  a collection with some elements like this

```
    ..
     "rMResults" : {
            "4" : {
                "decimal" : 19079,
                "formatted" : "190.79"
            },
            "5" : {
                "decimal" : 200000,
                "formatted" : "2000.00"
            },
            "6" : {
                "decimal" : 9467,
                "formatted" : "94.67"
            },
            "7" : {
                "decimal" : 32360,
                "formatted" : "323.60"
            }
        },
    ..
```

I would like to query all documents with matching "decimal"

I try with a query like this

```
    db.getCollection('events').find({  "rMResults": {
        $elemMatch: {
            7: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    decimal: 32360
                }
            }
        }
    } })
```

but no documents returned, could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to fetch the `elementMatch` on object where it works on **arrays**. Have a look at
[elementMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) 
In simple way to need to match and project the selected fields something like this,

```
db.getCollection('ACL').find({  "rMResults.7.decimal": 32360}, {"rMResults.7.decimal": true})
```